# mapstruct : replacing source

Tags: java, mapstruct

I see many examples of Mapper or @BeforeMapping that will modify the source object.

I would like to **substitute** the source object before mapping instead of modifying the source. Is this possible?

By example I would return an Enhanced class (CGlib) that would treat properties the way I want.

The idea behing it :

I am using MapStruct to convert @Entity to DTO. I want a smaller payload.
Now I set field to null depending on my "mappingContext" when these fields are not needed in the payload.

I would like as much as possible not to set field values in @Entity objects, as this could result in DB changes if objects are still attached to the session/EntityManager. (or this they are re-merged to db).

I would also like no to use "em.detach", as this would means my mapper is "magically" coupled with the the code before or after the mapping.

Comment: I think you should use 2 mappings chained together. One to make that intermediate DTO from you entity, and the other to map it to the final DTO. If I understood your problem incorrectly please provide some source code

Comment: that would work with a lot of boiler plate classes, and 2 mappers to maintain :)

Comment: Not sure that I get it, why substitute the source? Do you mean the target perhaps? MapStruct is not modifying the source

Comment: So then could you provide your source code so far?